# Jquery UI drag and drop issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to do a drag and drop using `Jquery` UI

I need drag and drop feature between two tables.

```
table1
<table class='table'>
....
 </table>

table2
<table class='table'>
....
 </table>
```

I want the user to drag `cell` from table 1 to table 2.

The codes below accomplish that

```
   var dragging =null;

   obj = $('.table td');

   $(obj).draggable({
       cursor:'pointer',
       snap:$('td span'),
       revert: 'invalid'      
   })

   $(obj).droppable({
       //only accept the drop if the cell is empty.
       accept: function(e){
          return $(this).text().trim()=="";
       },

       //replace anything items on table 2.
       drop:function(event, ui){
          $(this).html('&nbsp;').droppable( 'disable' );
       }
   })
```

My question is: After I drag the `itemA` from table 1 to table 2. I can't seem to drag `itemA` anymore on table 2. I want the user still be able to drag `itemA` even if it's in table 2.

I am not sure what went wrong here. Can anyone help me about it? thanks so much

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Xd6n/3/     thanks guys.

Comment: The problem in a nutshell is that your draggables are set to snap to a `<td>` element. When you drag the `<td>` element from one table to another, that `<td>` element ceases to exist in the original table, so when dragging it back it has nothing to snap to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is caused by making the `td` draggable and droppable. When you drag a `td` and drop it on another `td`, then you ***physically*** move the `td` out of the table, so the "drop" point changes.

Also I recommend against using `accept` in this manner.  When you call `$(this)` within your `accept` function, it returns ***all*** draggable objects.  Since you are really only concerned with the `td`'s content, I suggest approaching this in a different manner, using `drop` event to verify whether the `td` is empty or not.

```
$(function() {
var dragging =null;

   obj = $('.table td');

   //use obj since $(obj) is already jQuery object
   obj.draggable({
       cursor:'pointer',
       snap:$('td span'),
       revert: 'invalid',
       helper: 'clone',
       start: function( event, ui ) {
           //make helper same height as td
           $(ui.helper).css('height', $(this).height());
       }
   })

   obj.droppable({
       accept: obj, //make obj accept
       drop:function(event, ui){
           var target = $(event.target), //can also use $(this)
           drag = $(ui.draggable),
           targetText = "",
           dragText = "",
           duration = 0;

           if(target.text().trim() === ""){
               //store original target, drag text
               targetText = target.text().trim();
               dragText = drag.text().trim();

               //change html for each element
               target.html(dragText);
               drag.html(targetText);
           }
           else{
               //if not empty, change duration
               duration = 500;
           }

           //always have td revert
           //however, if invalid, the revertDuration will be default 
           //so the element "reverts"
           ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revertDuration', duration);
           ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert', true);

       }
   })
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/7Xd6n/4/

By doing it in this manner, only the content changes and the `td`s remain in the `table`.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with draggable is that the element your dragging doesn't actually move in the DOM. So when you try to drag it back to it's original position your are attempting to drop it upon itself.

Ideally, instead of dragging the `<td>` elements you should wrap the contents inside them in `<div>` elements and drag these instead.

The adjusted code would be something like this:

```
$(function() {

   draggable_obj = $('.table td div');
   droppable_obj = $('.table td');

   $(draggable_obj).draggable({
       cursor:'pointer',
       snap:'td',
       revert: 'invalid'   
   })

   $(droppable_obj).droppable({
       drop:function(event, ui){}
   })
});
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/jjyNS/

If you need the elements to move in the DOM too, then you may want to clone the element when it is dragged, hide the original, then when you drop it append the cloned element and remove the original.

Comment: I like your answer but I can't add div here. +1 though.